# Cannot run win32 exe on windows 7

Tags: delphi

I wrote a program using IdHTTP and IdFTP but I have a problem. I wrote it on windows XP 32 bit (using Delphi XE4) and the exe file (Project1.exe) works fine. When I try to open it on windows 7 64 bit, the computer gives me an error.

Picture: [image: click]

It means "You cannot acces to the path or the specified file. Maybe you don't have enough permissions". I've never seen this error before. Here you can see a picture of the folder with source code.

How can I solve my problem?

Here's the code:

```
function downloadSrc(var aUrl:ansiString):ansiString;
begin
 with tIdHttp.create(nil) do begin        //Create Indy http object
  request.userAgent:=INET_USERAGENT;      //Custom user agent string
  redirectMaximum:=INET_REDIRECT_MAX;     //Maximum redirects
  handleRedirects:=INET_REDIRECT_MAX<>0;  //Handle redirects
  readTimeOut:=INET_TIMEOUT_SECS*1000;    //Read timeout msec
  try                                     //Catch errors
   result:=get(aUrl);                     //Do the request
   if url.port='80' then url.port:='';    //Remove port 80 from final URL
   aUrl:=url.getFullURI                   //Return final URL
  except result:='error' end;             //Return an error message if failed
  free                                    //Free the http object
 end
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
if not(DirectoryExists('C:\mk7vrlist')) then
begin
  CreateDir('C:\mk7vrlist');
end;
ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
 for i := 0 to 59 do
   begin
     ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(40000+i*1000), nil);
   end;
ComboBox1.AddItem('99999', nil);
ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure TForm1.Label5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open',PChar('http://www.mk7vrlist.altervista.org'),nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var s:ansiString;
begin
 IdFTP1.Host:= 'mk7vrlist.altervista.org';
 IdFTP1.Username:='mk7vrlist';
 IdFTP1.Password:=pass;
 IdFTP1.Connect;
 s:='http://www.mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/test.txt';
 Memo1.Lines.Add(Edit1.Text+':'+ComboBox1.Text+':'+Edit2.Text);
 Memo1.Lines.Add(downloadSrc(s));
 Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('C:\mk7vrlist\test.txt');
 IdFTP1.ChangeDir('databases/');
 IdFTP1.Put('C:\mk7vrlist\test.txt');
 IdFTP1.Quit;
 IdFTP1.Disconnect;
 Label10.Visible:=True;
 Beep;
end;
```

Comment: This is an NTFS File permission problem, most likely. Is the program reading some other file and giving you this error? Or is this error happening AFTER your program runs, and it tries to read something else on your computer? You didn't say anything about what on the local computer this program accesses.

Also, it's more friendly to put the text of a purely text message right into your question. You can hit Ctrl-C and then use google translate to get the english text.

Comment: Are you trying to write on plain C:\ or folders like ProgramDir?

Comment: The program downloads a textfile on my server using winlnet and saves the text in c:\folder1\folder2\textfile.txt

Comment: It is probably an NTFS permission error writing to C:\folder1.  Are you aware that Windows 7 does not let you create folders as an ordinary user, under the root drive C: anymore?

Comment: try downloading it to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\YourProgramName - instead

Comment: I put the code I used if you want see what have I do. This error happens not only on my windows 7 computer, I've tested this program with a friend and he has the same problem.

Comment: You're probably running as Administrator and have UAC turned off, and your friend probably still has UAC on or is not running as an Administrator. This is a Windows permissions problem, not a Delphi programming problem. You're not following the rules about where you're allowed to store data; those rules were announced in Windows XP and started being enforced by default in Vista.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1615509/62576 for more information.

Comment: 1) I removed screenshot with source code, it is meaningless. 2) Change FTP password ASAP 3) Don't listen to them, they talk nonsense. First, assure you have write permissions to your `C:\mk7vrlist` directory and its subdirectories and see if error goes away when you grant current user a write access. And only then start considering where you want to store your files (and never store local application data in the roaming directory!).

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, just trying to save .INI files for my app on Windows 7.  My solution was the app data in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\[appfolder]`.  No more permission problems...  @KenWhite posted another link that shows several other locations where users commonly store data.  You should use an API call to resolve any path though so that your app will run on all versions of Windows.

Comment: Check this out. It contains various answers http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669244

Comment: Thank you for translating the error message for us (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your account has administrative rights, right click on your program's icon, and invoke 'run as administrator' - you will get prompted/warned - click yes.

I don't believe the problem is 32->64 bit, but going from XP to Win 7, which by default is more particular about access.

You can set up a shortcut configured always to run it as admin, to avoid the right click step, but you will still get prompted/warned.

Comment: That's a quicker way to confirm if the cause of error is filesystem permissions.

Comment: When our dev environment at work migrated from XP to Win 7, at first I was having a lot of similar problems. Sys admin told me use the 'run as administrator option' - since then no problems.

Comment: Cannot agree with your last edit, running the application elevated is a good diagnostic idea to confirm what unclear Italian error is really caused by f/s ACLs, but in no way it is a good permanent solution.

Comment: @user539484 :   He's a developer, and I assume developing. This is a site for developers and development problems, no? I have been working that way for 2 years, every day using XE - certain things I cannot debug correctly otherwise - nothing wrong with saving time. If and when he has to deploy to users, that's a different issue entirely.

Comment: I removed the folder 'C:\mk7vrlist' and I opened the program but I still have the error. I've also noticed that the program doesn't start because I put "CreateDir('C:\mk7vrlist');" on the Form.onCreate event, but I don't see the new folder

Comment: 2 two years of UAC prompt every day? This is gross. @user2420829, did you finally figured out if you have write permission or not?

Comment: @Mikey You have got it all wrong. You aren't making things easier for yourself. Making things easier would be avoiding uac prompts by 1. Understanding UAC and 2. Putting that understanding to use. I agree with all of user539484's comments to the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-You have got it all wrong: I work in an environment where I personally have no control over UAC-a BIG corporation in a very tightly regulated industry. All workstations are cloned from an image which is locked down, and I work as a contractor-an outsider. In addition, as a programmer interested in programming, Linux and openSource, I have neither the need nor the desire to devote my energy to understanding MS's security model: I go to work, code my Delphi, and come home to Linux with C++ and Python -technologies that interest me. One extra mouse click a day doesn't bother me.

Comment: -1. Sorry. I have to agree with @David. If your app has no need for admin access, you should write it so it works properly without needing it. Being too lazy to learn how to work with security simply means you're defeating the benefits of having that security, and (no offense, but doing it anyway), that's simply dumb. If you're in a "very tightly regulated industry" (and we've discussed where you work before <g>), your system admin is doing a very poor job. It's been a decade since MS started to enforce UAC; there's no excuse ad a developer not to understand it by now and work with it.

Comment: (continued) And this question is about software being distributed, which means that "He's a developer" doesn't apply. It's a problem with not working properly with the security levels that are *typically applied* to user's machines, and that's just bad development.

Comment: @KenWhite - Please: Do not make a mountain out of a molehill here. I just answered the question as stated by suggesting he try what I tried and which works for me every day when I fire up Delphi XE, that's all. You don't like my sys admins? Talk to them... I'm just a little contractor trying to make a living in a very big corporation that has a few in-house developers who are not their primary focus. :-)

Comment: No mountain. :-) I disagree with your solution, and I downvoted it. I happen to be a sysadmin as well as a developer. I don't know your sys admins, but if they're recommending that you circumvent proper UAC requirements by running as an admin user, they're not qualified for the jobs they have. Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is to modify the program so that it writes to the proper locations.

Comment: @Mikey Your admins don't need talking to. You do. They are right to make you run with UAC on. Then you can dog food your code. Your users will have to suffer the same way you do. I develop on machines with UAC dialed all the way up. I never see a UAC dialog with my app. It's really not hard to do it right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I'm afraid we are not talking about the same thing... you have not read my comments carefully. :-)

Comment: I think I understand perfectly well. I see no evidence that you have any need to run elevated by default. And you yourself confess to not understanding UAC.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : As you like it.

Answer (score 0):

> > CreateDir('C:\mk7vrlist)

Normal users do not have that kind of access to c:\

Do something like this instead (pseudo code):

CreateDir('%temp%\mk7vrlist)

Comment: `CreateDir` does not expand `%temp%`, so this won't work. You need to properly ask for the `Temp` folder location using the API.

Comment: I noted it. That's why I didn't downvote. :-) But it's not really an answer; it's more of a comment. Answers provide a solution to the problem, and "do something like (this pseudocode)" doesn't do provide one.